# Running hive Queries using python hive utils module

Tags: python, hadoop

I have a machine with hadoop and hive all configured,up and running. Now I have a remote server with python 2.7.5 (all necessary packages installed) from which I want to remotely execute hive queries on the hadoop machine. I chose python hive_utils package for this (There are other modules that can be used but I am interested to know why hive_utils didn't work on my machine)

Here is the code I am trying:

import hive_utils

```
query = """
SELECT *
FROM testibname20;
"""  
hive_client = hive_utils.HiveClient(
    server='192.168.151.80',
    port=10000,
    db='default'
)    
a = hive_client.execute(query)  
a = list(a)
```

When I run this code,It doesn't throw any error that I can investigate further, instead it just hangs there and does nothing. I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Please try to make this work using hive_utils rather than suggesting me another python modules to make this work.

Comment: it might not be an error. Have you tried printing the list

Comment: able to connect with that port ? using beeline ?

Comment: @NirmalRam - Yes I tries printing the list but still the programs hangs and no output shown

Comment: Can you able to start beeline connecting to hive thrift server and view the 'testibname20' table ?
From $HIVE_HOME
`bin/beeline`
`beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://192.168.151.80:10000`

Comment: yes I am able to connect and view the table from beeline

Comment: I tried restarting the thrift server on hive machine. Now after restarting the server, the program doesn't hang but throws this error:                   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/hive_metastore/ThriftHiveMetastore.py", line 622, in recv_get_database
    raise x
thrift.Thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'get_database'